# MySQL Date Format in Create Table

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have to create a table with MySql which can store date in the following format : I tried smth like :

```
CREATE TABLE birth (
....
    date      DATE,
......

);
```

But it doesn't work since DATE format is YYYY/MM/DD... How can I do ?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dates do not have a "format" in MySQL (or in almost any other database).  They are stored in some internal format, that is eventually presented to the user.

If you want the date in a particular format, use `dateformat()` for output.  In your case, `dateformat(datecol, '%Y/%m/%d')`.

For input, use the ISO standard format (YYYY-MM-DD) or `str_to_date()` with the same formatting conventions.