# Reformat input DATE data

Tags: mysql, datetime, mariadb, preprocessor

I have a rather large (over 200,000 records) file that I am inserting into a table with 59 columns.  The data contains several DATETIME fields.  The input dates are in the form '10/06/2019 10:45:58'.  How can I input these fields as DATETIME (or maybe just DATE, since the TIME field is irrelevant for my purposes)?

If I set the various date fields to type DATETIME, the fields come up as 0000-00-00 00:00:00 after loading.  That's because the database does not know what to do with the input format.

I see two different approaches, but each has issues:

**Preprocessing**:
I create a script to detect the date fields using Regex and reformat them to the expected form using something like Perl's DateTime::Format::DBI.  There is a risk here since the records include freeform TEXT fields that may contain embedded commas and quotes.  Positively identifying the DATE fields is difficult just because of scale.

**Post-processing**:
Create the table with the date fields as VARCHAR and use the STR_TO_DATE SQL function populate the date columns.

```
INSERT INTO mytable(DATELastDetected, DATEFirstDetected) 
  SELECT STR_TO_DATE(LastDetected, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), 
  STR_TO_DATE(FirstDetected, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i') 
from mytable;
```

**Third Option?**
I've wondered whether I might specify the expected format of the input data for that DATE columns in the CREATE TABLE statement, which would render the whole discussion moot.  I've seen [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184398/mysql-date-format-in-create-table) that mentions the use of DATEFORMAT in a CREATE TABLE statement, but I have not found the right syntax to use.

Appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: I would go the preprocessing route, which would include date validation and then conversion.

Comment: The E-Z way is you just convert the date-time as part of the CSV Load.
 You just use `str_to_date()` as part of the the Data load statement you are supplying to SQL/MySQL for the given column. Easy-Peasy.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163079/importing-a-csv-to-mysql-with-different-date-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ben-personick answered it with his comment.  Here's what my Load statement looks like:

```
    LOAD DATA INFILE '/opt/mysql/work/report.csv'
        INTO TABLE `my_db`.`tbl_reportdata`
    CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        ESCAPED BY '"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
        IGNORE 1
        LINES (`IP`,
[...]
                `OS`,
                @FirstDetectedVar,# This field is defined as DATETIME
                @LastDetectedVar, # This field is defined as DATETIME
[...]
                `Category`)
        set
        `FirstDetected` = str_to_date(@FirstDetectedVar, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i'),
        `LastDetected` = str_to_date(@LstDetectedVar, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i');
```

I figured the answer was out there.  Hopefully this working example will help someone else.